# Mysql запрос параметров (3 нормальная форма) с фильтром.

Tags: mysql

Таблицы:

```
table1:
id|title

table2:
t1_id|name|value
```

Запрос:

```
select `table1`.`title` as `title`,
GROUP_CONCAT(if(`name` = 'param1', `value`, NULL)) AS 'PARAM1',
GROUP_CONCAT(if(`name` = 'param2', `value`, NULL)) AS 'PARAM2',
GROUP_CONCAT(if(`name` = 'param3', `value`, NULL)) AS 'PARAM3'
from `table1` left join `table2` on `table1`.`id`=`table2`.`t1_id`
group by `table2`.`t1_id`
```

Задача: сделать фильтр по param1, param2,... etc.
У меня получилось только обрамив этот запрос еще одним:

```
select * from(МОЙ-ЗАПРОС) as `sub` where `PARAM1`='SOME_VALUE'
```

Второй вариант - начать выборку с таблицы параметров, то есть, выбирать t1_id, которые соответствуют параметрам, но там тоже двойной запрос получается.
Как это делают умные люди?

P.S.

1) меня устроит ссылка на мануал, в т.ч. английская
2) меня не устроит процедура
3) меня устроит пинок, что такая тема уже была, но со ссылкой на тему.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вариант с group_concat довольно оригинальный, впрочем от mysql можно и не такого ожидать :)

Стандартный запрос будет выглядеть так:

```
select t1.title, t21.value as param1, t22.value as param2, t23.value as param3
from table1 t1
  left join table2 t21 on t1.id = t21.t1_id and t21.name='param1'
  left join table2 t22 on t1.id = t22.t1_id and t22.name='param2'
  left join table2 t23 on t1.id = t23.t1_id and t23.name='param3'
where
  t21.value = 'abc'
  and t22.value like '%some value%'
  and t23.value between 100 and 200
```

**N.B.** Нужен индекс по t1_id+name

Comment: Вариант с `GROUP_CONCAT()` хоть и оригинальный, но менее эффективный. С ним при выборке не воспользуешься индексом по `table2.name`.

Comment: +100500.
Это ГОРАЗДО быстрее. раз в 50
Даже без индекса второй таблицы вариант @Yura_Ivanov ищет за 0,5с.
Спасибо.

Comment: Следует отметить, что таблица со значениями параметров должна содержать не название параметра, а id параметра. Иначе возможна ситуация, что размер индекса по t1_id+name будет приводить к ситуации, что индекс по t1_id будет работать в итоге быстрее.  

Правильнее завести таблицу параметров, где описывать метаданные каждого параметра (название параметра, тип значения, виды фильтров и т.д.), и строить запрос циклом по этой таблице. Построив такой запрос можно создать view на его основе со всем параметрами, выборку делать из него, работая как с обычной таблицей.

Comment: Правильнее завести таблицу параметров, где описывать метаданные каждого параметра// Я об этом уже думал. Только как эту таблицу подключить. Таким же образом? Там же тоже будут, грубо говоря, ключ-значение

Comment: @knes, там есть смысл хранить общую информацию по метаполям: id, название поля, описание, тип данных, и т.д. А в `table2` вместо `name` хранить `id_field` который будет ссылаться на `id` этой самой таблицы метаполей.

Comment: Да это я понял.

table1:
id|title
table2:
id_t1|id_param|value
table3
id|name|type

Но как подсосать названия параметров? Вот я и спрашиваю: таким же left-join?

Comment: Названия параметров можно сразу при формировании запроса включить в него в качестве названия поля, тогда лишние join'ы будут не нужны. Как в ответе

    select t21.value as `param1`

Собирается по таблице параметров и псевдоним подставляется как имя параметра (псевдоним может быть произвольным же, не обязательно латиницей).  
Есть еще вариант для итерации по параметрам:

    select "param1" as paramname_1, t21.value as `param1`

тогда можно не знать названия параметров а обращаться к ним по индексу: 

    $result[$result["paramname_".$i]];

Answer (score 3):

Буквально на днях подобную штуку программил.

```
SELECT t1.*
FROM table1 t1
INNER JOIN table2 p1 ON (p1.t1_id=t1.id) AND (p1.name="param1") AND (p1.value="value1")
INNER JOIN table2 p2 ON (p2.t1_id=t1.id) AND (p2.name="param1") AND (p2.value="value1")
```

Сколько условий по кастомным полям столько и `INNER JOIN`-ов

Этот паттерн называется Entity Attribute Value (EAV)

Comment: >Сколько условий по кастомным полям столько и INNER JOIN-ов

Ой, нет. Тогда лучше я буду как раньше.
Че-то мне кажется, это получится в разы дольше. Ча проверю.

Comment: Если в `table2` проиндексировать `t1_id` и `name`, то не так все плохо как может показаться. Но важно помнить про ограничение в 61 JOIN.

Comment: А еще можно вместо одного `value` сделать `int_value`, `float_value`, `date_value`, `text_value`. Чтобы данные хранились в нативном виде, и их тоже можно было бы индексировать.

Comment: @knes, как раньше - это фильтровать через where?

Comment: 61 JOIN - некритично.

Comment: это фильтровать через where?// да. Именно. из уже готовой выборки с одним джойном. Не?

Comment: Последнюю часть условия в `JOIN`-е можно перенести в `WHERE`. Но разницы никакой нет. Если нужно делать выборку по нескольким критериям и при этом хочется менять параметры только в `WHERE`, нужно делать как предложил @Yura Ivanov. Я в своем проекте сделал конструктор, который добавлял `INNER JOIN`-ы в тело запроса. Зачем подключать лишние таблицы когда они не нужны.

Comment: По поводу лишних джойнов, зависит от оптимизатора. Например, в sybase'е проверял, что если в таком запросе поля одного джойна не участвуют в выборке, то на план запроса таблица влиять не будет, т.е. вообще будет опущена.

Comment: Судя по результатам `EXPLAIN` оптимизатор в MySQL не такой умный как хотелось бы. При обработке запроса c `LEFT JOIN` таблица все равно подключается, несмотря на то, что она нигде не используется, и уникальный индекс однозначно говорит о том что объединение будет один к одному.

Answer (score 0):

ИМХО, лучший подход это когда Вы продумываете логику PHP-скрипта и пишите фильтрацию на нем. Для примера: скрипт с 3 `INNER JOIN` загружает информацию спустя 3-4 секунды, с 4 уже 25-30 секунд. Данные не с потолка, а с реального проекта. Фильтрацию должен делать PHP.