# Поиск с умным фильтром в интернет-магазине

Tags: php, mysql

Здравствуйте, хочу понять логику фильтров для поиска товаров. Примеры сайтов: 
[пример 1](http://market.yandex.ru/search?hid=7811947), [пример 2](http://www.ulmart.ru/photo_cameras/?r=1__75075;1__90439;3__64)  (левое меню). Я, конечно, представляю все это дело, и могу набросать парочку sql запросов и создать под них таблицы, но чувствую в итоге получиться плохой код. Расскажите, пожалуйста, логику.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

С фотоаппаратами все просто. там три поля бренд и цена рейтинг и еще одна таблица для наличия на разных складах. Т.е. для данного случая подойдет простейший вариант с прошитыми полями...

Сложный вариант - яндекс, который заранее не знает какие товары в нем лежат, позволяет накладывать фильтр на любые свойства и характеристики. Для этого подойдет паттерн EAV (который недавно [обсуждали](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/147160/mysql-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81-%D0%BF%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2-3-%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F-%D1%84%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BC%D0%B0-%D1%81-%D1%84%D0%B8%D0%BB%D1%8C%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BC) - тут описан и запрос для фильтра).

Для каждого товара в отдельной таблице или таблицах, разделенных по типу значений, хранятся значения свойств. Таблица описания свойств является настроечной и вспомогательной, по которой строится запрос для фильтрации. А также по ней строятся фильтры, т.е. какого вида фильтр - перечисление (синий, красный) или диапазоны (от и до ну если есть такие свойства, не путать с ценой).

По поводу цен. Цена товара может зависеть от каких-то свойств. Например обувь от размера или мебель от материала, были случаи что цена зависела от магазина (на Рублевке дороже). Возможны следующие варианты:

- Первый вариант. Делаем каждую комбинацию для таких товаров отдельным товаром. Просто хранить, но в списке товаров имеем кучу одинаковых позиций в разных цветах но с разной а может быть и одинаковой ценой. Старый вариант, раньше так и торговали, но вывод списка товаров в удобном виде выглядел нетривиальной задачей, с дистинктами, с головным элементом и прочим геморроем. Ну и вообще не третья НФ.
- Второй вариант. Таблица с характеристиками. Характеристика - это сочетание различных свойств, для которых однозначно определяется цена и количество. Например, Белые тапочки 48 размера в Теплом стане остались одни за $1000. В этом случае ведем две таблицы (товар, характеристика, цена) и (товар, характеристика, склад, количество). Поскольку каждая характеристика состоит из таких же свойств как и для товара, получается, что мы можем использовать фильтр и для свойств, входящих в характеристику.

Если совсем углубляться, то фильтр товаров может меняться в зависимости от группы. Например фотоаппараты различаются мегапикселями и зумом, а мониторы - дюймами и временем отклика.
Таким образом, в зависимости от свойств товаров и свойств характеристик, которые наполняют данную группу фильтр должен быть свой. И глобального фильтра по всем товарам каталога быть не должно, мухи отдельно, котлеты отдельно. Связь между разными аксессуарами (картриджи к принтерам) реализуется дополнительными развязками, тут каждый волен выбирать себе схему по своему вкусу.